# Android Fragment containing a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Trying to get a list view feeded with data inside a fragment.
By my knowing the code I have should work but it doesn't. Als tried to use ListFragment instead of Fragment and BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter but both won't work.

**Fragment**

```
public class ContactsFragment extends Fragment {
  private DashboardActivity dashboard;
  private List<User> contacts;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
    ...
    ...
    ListView contactsListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);

    ContactsListAdapter contactsListAdapter = new ContactsListAdapter(getActivity(), contacts);

    contactsListView.setAdapter(contactsListAdapter);

    return rootView;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class ContactsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {

  private Context context;
  private List<User> contacts;

  public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, List<User> contacts) {
      super(context, R.layout.contact_list_item);

      this.context = context;
      this.contacts = contacts;
  }
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    User contact = contacts.get(position);

    View contactView = convertView;

    if (contactView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        contactView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView contactEmail = (TextView)contactView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_email);
    contactEmail.setText(contact.getEmail());

    TextView contactPhone = (TextView)contactView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_phone);
    contactPhone.setText(contact.getPhone());

    return contactView;
}
```

Did I miss something? Perhaps using other base classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ContactsListAdapter(Context context, List<User> contacts) {
   super(context, R.layout.contact_list_item,contacts); //change here
   this.context = context;
   this.contacts = contacts;
}
```

Comment: Ow man, I am so stupid. Just couldn't find the problem.
Big thanks for helping me out here!!!!